# Making sibling as Child

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my xml that I want to translate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Loop xmlns="http://www.example.org">
<Loop-2000A>
  <Element-628>81</Element-628>
  <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
  <Element-735>83</Element-735>
  <Element-736>84</Element-736>
</Loop-2000A>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>85</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>
</Loop-2000B>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>98</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
</Loop-2000B>

<Loop-2000A>
  <Element-628>89</Element-628>
  <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
  <Element-735>99</Element-735>
  <Element-736>109</Element-736>
</Loop-2000A>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>208</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>

</Loop-2000B>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>209</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
</Loop-2000B>
</Loop>
```

The requirement is to make the ...A elements parents of ...B elements. Hence, the transformed XML should look something like this...

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:TargetLoop xmlns:ns2="http://www.target.org"> 
  <Loop-2000A>
   <Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>85</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>

</Loop-2000B>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>98</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
</Loop-2000B>
  <Element-628>81</Element-628>
  <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
  <Element-735>83</Element-735>
  <Element-736>84</Element-736>
</Loop-2000A>



<Loop-2000A>
   <Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>208</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>

</Loop-2000B>
<Loop-2000B>
  <Element-1035>209</Element-1035>
  <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
  <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
</Loop-2000B>
  <Element-628>89</Element-628>
  <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
  <Element-735>99</Element-735>
  <Element-736>109</Element-736>
</Loop-2000A>
```

I tried following xsl logic however, it is not giving desired results. Can someone please help ?

```
`<xsl:template match="/">
<ns2:TargetLoop>
<xsl:for-each select="/ns1:Loop/ns1:Loop-2000A">
  <ns2:RepeatedLoop>

<ns2:Loop-2000A>

<xsl:call-template name="setLoopB">
<xsl:with-param name="a"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</ns2:Loop-2000A>


</ns2:RepeatedLoop>
</xsl:for-each>
</ns2:TargetLoop>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="setLoopB">
<xsl:param name="a"/>
<ns2:Loop-2000B>

</ns2:Loop-2000B>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`
```

This is not giving desired result. I am struggling big time for this requirement.Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: No Tim.I can just use xslt 1.0.That is what supported in my environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org" exclude-result-prefixes="ex">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="ex:Loop-2000B" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000A[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/ex:Loop">
  <ns2:TargetLoop xmlns:ns2="http://www.target.org">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Loop-2000A"/>
  </ns2:TargetLoop>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex:Loop-2000A">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', generate-id())"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Saxon 6.5 transforms your input sample into

```
<ns2:TargetLoop xmlns:ns2="http://www.target.org">
   <Loop-2000A>
      <Loop-2000B>
         <Element-1035>85</Element-1035>
         <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
         <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>
      </Loop-2000B>
      <Loop-2000B>
         <Element-1035>98</Element-1035>
         <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
         <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
      </Loop-2000B>
      <Element-628>81</Element-628>
      <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
      <Element-735>83</Element-735>
      <Element-736>84</Element-736>
   </Loop-2000A>
   <Loop-2000A>
      <Loop-2000B>
         <Element-1035>208</Element-1035>
         <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
         <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>
      </Loop-2000B>
      <Loop-2000B>
         <Element-1035>209</Element-1035>
         <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
         <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
      </Loop-2000B>
      <Element-628>89</Element-628>
      <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
      <Element-735>99</Element-735>
      <Element-736>109</Element-736>
   </Loop-2000A>
</ns2:TargetLoop>
```

If you have other elements then try

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org" exclude-result-prefixes="ex">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="ex:Loop-2000B" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000A[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="/ex:Loop">
  <ns2:TargetLoop xmlns:ns2="http://www.target.org">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ex:Loop-2000B)]"/>
  </ns2:TargetLoop>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex:Loop-2000A">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', generate-id())"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin.That worked like charm...one more calification,If I have few more elements just above <Loop-2000A> in source and I want them to transform as it is to target.what should I do.As this transformation is removing if any element is also existing above <Loop-2000A>

Comment: @user3151878, I have added a new version of the XSLT but it is untested. If you still have problems then ask a new question with complete XML input and output samples.

Comment: Hi Martin..Please excuse me for not asking a separate question beacuse context is already set.In above example if I have <Loop-2000C> also as sibling of <Loop-2000B>.And I want to make <Loop-2000C> also as child of <Loop-2000A>,how to change above code.Can u please throw some light.Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider to ask a new question with a new input and wanted result sample.

Comment: Hi Martin,I have asked another question here.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587075/sibling-as-child