# Sibling as Child

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my xml that I want to translate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Loop xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <Loop-2000A>
    <Element-628>81</Element-628>
    <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
    <Element-735>83</Element-735>
    <Element-736>84</Element-736>
  </Loop-2000A>
  <Loop-2000B>
    <Element-1035>85</Element-1035>
    <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>
  </Loop-2000B>
  <Loop-2000B>
    <Element-1035>98</Element-1035>
    <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
  </Loop-2000B>
  <Loop-2000C>
    <Element-1031>86</Element-1031>
    <Element-1039 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1038>25</Element-1038>
  </Loop-2000C>

  <Loop-2000A>
    <Element-628>89</Element-628>
    <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
    <Element-735>99</Element-735>
    <Element-736>109</Element-736>
  </Loop-2000A>
  <Loop-2000B>
    <Element-1035>208</Element-1035>
    <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>

  </Loop-2000B>
  <Loop-2000C>
    <Element-1031>92</Element-1031>
    <Element-1039 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1038>90</Element-1038>
  </Loop-2000C>
  <Loop-2000B>
    <Element-1035>209</Element-1035>
    <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
    <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
  </Loop-2000B>
</Loop>
```

The requirement is to make the ...Loop-2000A  parents of ...Loop-2000B  ..and Loop-2000B Parents of 2000-C . Loop2000-C is optional in source xml.Other Loop in xml which are outside Loop-2000A should be transformed as it is.  Hence, the transformed XML should look something like this.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:TargetLoop xmlns:ns2="http://www.target.org"> 
  <Loop-2000A>
    <Loop-2000B>
      <Element-1035>85</Element-1035>
      <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
      <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>

    </Loop-2000B>
    <Loop-2000B>
      <Element-1035>98</Element-1035>
      <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
      <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
      <Loop-2000C>
        <Element-1031>86</Element-1031>
        <Element-1039 nil="nil86"/>
        <Element-1038>25</Element-1038>
      </Loop-2000C>
    </Loop-2000B>
    <Element-628>81</Element-628>
    <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
    <Element-735>83</Element-735>
    <Element-736>84</Element-736>
  </Loop-2000A>



  <Loop-2000A>
   <Loop-2000B>
      <Element-1035>208</Element-1035>
      <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
      <Element-1037>87</Element-1037>
      <Loop-2000C>
        <Element-1031>92</Element-1031>
        <Element-1039 nil="nil86"/>
        <Element-1038>90</Element-1038>
      </Loop-2000C>
    </Loop-2000B>
    <Loop-2000B>
      <Element-1035>209</Element-1035>
      <Element-1036 nil="nil86"/>
      <Element-1037>97</Element-1037>
    </Loop-2000B>
    <Element-628>89</Element-628>
    <Element-734 nil="nil82"/>
    <Element-735>99</Element-735>
    <Element-736>109</Element-736>
  </Loop-2000A>
</Loop>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try anything or do you expect us to do all the work?

Comment: Are you assuming that there is a single B, and at most one C, following each A and that those are the ones to pick up?  If so, the biggest challenge is not picking up a C from a subsequent A.

Comment: Hi Thomas..I am quite new to xsl,so please excuse me for elementary things.I am sorry...

Comment: Hi Keshlam...there can be multiple B between two A.And can be atmost one C after each B.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: no Tim..it is xslt1.0 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could have probably made use of **xsl:for-each-group**, using its **group-starting-with** attribute. In XSLT 1.0 though, this can be achieved by use of keys. You can define a key to look up the **Loop-2000B** elements by their first preceding **Loop-2000A** element

```
<xsl:key name="B" match="ex:Loop-2000B" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000A[1])" />
```

Similarlym you could do the same for associating **Loop-2000C** elements by their first preceding **Loop-2000B** element (Although this may not be necessary if you say there can be at most only one **Loop-2000C** element for each **Loop-2000B**

```
<xsl:key name="C" match="ex:Loop-2000C" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000B[1])" />
```

The **generate-id** function is an XSLT function that can be used to generate a unique id for each node (If one of their existing child elements could uniquely identify the element, you could also use that). Note the use of the **ex:** prefix is because all the elements in your XML are in a namespace, so XSLT needs to know which namespaces elements are in.

In your XSLT you would start off by selecting just the **Loop-2000A** elements.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Loop-2000A" />
```

Then, within the template that matches **ex:Loop-2000A** you would select all the associated **ex:Loop-2000B** elements using the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('B', generate-id(current()))" />
```

You would take a similar approach for getting the **ex:Loop-2000C** in the template that matches **ex:Loop-2000B**. Although, if there was ever only going to be at most one such **ex:Loop-2000C** element, you could do this and not worry about the key in this case:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::ex:Loop-2000C]" />
```

This gets the very following sibling element, but only if it is a **Loop-2000C** element.

Finally, other existing elements can be matched and copied with the Identity Transform

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:ex="http://www.example.org">

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="B" match="ex:Loop-2000B" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000A[1])" />
  <xsl:key name="C" match="ex:Loop-2000C" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::ex:Loop-2000B[1])" />

  <xsl:template match="*[ex:Loop-2000A]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Loop-2000A" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ex:Loop-2000A)][not(self::ex:Loop-2000B)][not(self::ex:Loop-2000C)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ex:Loop-2000A">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('B', generate-id(current()))" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ex:Loop-2000B">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('C', generate-id(current()))" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim Thanks a lot for your valuable reply.It is very detailed and took lot of your time ...one small doubt.I have few more elements just above element <Loop-2000A>.I want them to to be copied as it is in target xml.....I tried <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ns1:Loop-2000B)]"/>....instead of <xsl:apply-templates select="ex:Loop-2000A" />....it copied all elements but also copied Loop-2000C as sibling.Can you please tell what modification I should do.

Comment: I've made a tweak to the first template, which I hope is what you want. For future reference, you really do need to make sure your XML in your question is an accurate representation of what you are using. Thank you!